# Enable disabled html button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to test forms where the client has requested that the submit button be disabled by default.  I was wanting to see if there would be a way to replace the `disabled=""` with `enabled` via javascript that I could use in a script manager?  Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
    <button type="submit" disabled="" class="btn btn-default btn-block margin-top-10 pull-left padding-left-30 padding-right-30" name="Submit"><span>Send</span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `enabled` attribute.

Clear the `disabled` property.

```
document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").disabled = false;
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out immensely.